# Flutter logs don't work in Xcode console after upgrading to Flutter 2.5

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, logging

I have updated Flutter to 2.5 and Xcode to 12.5.1. Since then, when I run the app on Xcode, no logs from Flutter code are displayed, only the logs in the native iOS code.

This is the default log I use which doesn't work now:

```
print('default print');
```

I have tried this log:

```
import 'dart:developer';
log('test log');
```

and it also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?